# Website that allows Twitter-like message accessed via TinyURL

Tags: twitter

Looking for a website that allows me to post Twitter-like messages that are accessed via TinyURLs and that allows me to create an account to get reports on the access of each of these messages.

Basically, unlikely Twitter, each message would require the TinyURL for to access the message, but there would be no central author index of messages.  Also, the author would not only be able to login and see a centralized listing of all the messages, but also reports on if the messages had been accessed.

Comment: It can be easily built with Wordpress, a short domain and for the stats: Google Analytics.

Comment: +1 @Osvaldo: Posted an answer, using Wordpress to me seems a bit like overkill, but without exact details on how you'd deploy it, it is hard to say. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tinypaste.com](http://tinypaste.com)

Fits all of the stated requirements:

- Shorten URLs
- Text returned when url loaded
- Reports on loads